# How to get 5 character from right with sql using laravel eloquent?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

i have my sql query like this `SELECT max(RIGHT(request_number, 5)) FROM farmers` and i want to convert it to the laravel eloquent.. did you guys have any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only raw query way like this:

```
$result = \DB::table('farmers')
          ->select(\DB::raw('max(RIGHT(request_number, 5)) as result'))
          ->get();
```

Then to get it:

```
{{ array_get($result[0], 'result') }}
```

Comment: okay i will try.. and 1 more question, i got this data format in return  `array:1 [▼
  0 => {#407 ▼
    +"max(RIGHT(request_number, 5))": "00010"
  }
]`, how to get that value? (00010)

Comment: Added another answer below

Comment: Ok I have reedited. Add: `as result` or something to your query

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = \DB::table('farmers')
      ->select(\DB::raw('max(RIGHT(request_number, 5)) as request_number_result'))
      ->get();
```

You can access this via

```
$result[0]['request_number_result']
```